# IFS not parsing well CSV

Tags: bash, ifs

I am trying to parse a file so I can obtain the first column. The command I'm using is:

```
while IFS=',' read -r a; do echo "$a"; done < test.csv
```

However it is still outputting the whole csv instead of the first column. An example of the csv is as follows:

```
NOM,CODI,DATA,SEXE,GRUP_EDAT,RESIDENCIA,CASOS_CONFIRMAT,PCR,INGRESSOS_TOTAL,INGRESSOS_CRITIC,INGRESSATS_TOTAL,INGRESSATS_CRITIC,EXITUS
    MOIANÃS,42,24/08/2020,Home,Majors de 74,No,0,2,0,0,0,0,0
    ALT CAMP,01,30/07/2020,Dona,Entre 15 i 64,Si,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    ALT CAMP,01,30/07/2020,Dona,Entre 65 i 74,No,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
    ALT CAMP,01,30/07/2020,Dona,Entre 65 i 74,Si,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

I've been looking elsewhere and all seem to agree that this should be the correct approach when parsing csv using IFS. A thing I've noticed is that if I add a new column to the read function, say b, it outputs the first column instead of everything.

```
while IFS=',' read -r a b; do echo "$a"; done < test.csv
```

I don't understand this behaviour and it does not seem to work further than printing the first column. For example, If I were to put c and $c, it wouldn't print the third column and so on.

Can you please explain this behaviour and why this is happening?

Thank you

Comment: You should read the description of the `read` command. http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/readh.html

Comment: If your data has been touched by an MS-Windows machine, check with `cat -vet file | head -10`. If you see `^M$` at the end of each line, then convert your file to *nix format with `dos2unix file`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bash` is not the right tool for parsing a csv file and you should consider `awk` for this. e.g. to printf first 2 columns use this super simple awk command:

```
awk -F, '{print $1, $2}' file.csv
```

Just to highlight your issue: Regarding your `bash` loop, better use an array to ready all comma separated columns into array:

```
while IFS=, read -ra arr; do
    # print first 2 columns
    echo "col1=${arr[0]}, col2=${arr[1]}"
done < file.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

`read` is working correctly.  It splits on IFS and assigns each field to a variable, with the remainder of the line going to the last variable.  If you only give one variable, the whole line goes to it.

Comment: I don't think that's the case here. If it put `while IFS=',' read -r a b; do echo "$a $b"; done < test.csv`, it doesn't output the first two columns. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @js352 _It splits on IFS and assigns each field to a variable [first field to `$a`], with the remainder of the line going to the last variable [`$b`]._ In your `while` try to `echo $a` or `echo $b`.

Answer (score 2):

For *simple* CSV files, you can simply split on every comma, but you want to read the input into an *array*, unless you know the number of columns in every row.

For exapmle, if you know there are going to be (at most) 10 columns, you can use

```
while IFS=, read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9 f10; do
```

However, in `bash` it is simpler to read the entire split line into a single *array*:

```
while IFS=, read -ra f; do
```

The first field would be `"${f[0]}"`, the second `"${f[1]}"`, etc.